# Are these propositions logically equivalent?

Tags: logic

Are these logically equivalent? $\sim\exists y(\forall x\exists zP(x,y,z)\vee\exists x\forall zQ(x,y,z))$ and $\forall y(\exists x\forall z\sim P(x,y,z)\wedge\forall x\exists z\sim Q(x,y,z))$. The way  I see it, we have the same outside the parenthesis but the opposite on the inside. Am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The outside are also opposites: "there is no $y$" in the first, "for any $y$" in the second

Answer (score 1):

Here, I assume by $\sim$ you mean negation.

I believe the two statements are equivalent. There are two things going on here:

First, the negation of an existential statement, and the negation of a universal statement is an existential one. For example, say $R$ is some predicate, then $\sim \exists x R(x)$ is equivalent to $\forall x \sim R(x)$.

Secondly, $\sim (R(x)\lor S(x))$ is equivalent to $(\sim R(x)\land \sim S(x))$.

Let us define $A:=∀x∃zP(x,y,z)$ and $B:=∃x∀zQ(x,y,z)$. Then your first expression states

$$
\sim \exists y (A\lor B),
$$
and, as you note, the portion inside the parentheses is negated in the second expression. The second expression can be written as
$$
\forall y (\sim A \land \sim B).
$$

I hope this clarifies any confusion.